# Como fazer update recuperando valor de outra tabela?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela no meu BD, chamada `contas`. Onde eu registro todas as contas do sistema.

Assim que elas são pagas eu realizo um `update` mudando o status dela. Porém, mando um único update para várias contas, da seguinte maneira:

```
update contas
set status='0',
    valor_recebido='aqui preciso capturar o campo valor'
where id IN ($ids)
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém no campo `valor_recebido` eu preciso capturar o valor do campo `valor` da mesma tabela `conta`.

Alguém sabe se isso e possível?

Eu realizar um `update` e ao mesmo tempo atribuir o valor de um campo da tabela, a outro campo?

Comment: Não é só trocar `valor_recebido=seuCampo`?

Comment: aff serio que e tão simples assim, pqp não sabia, vlw mesmo

Comment: deu certo aqui vlw mesmo hahahahah

Comment: Bom que pude ajudar. :). rsrs

Comment: posta isso como resposta ai para eu marcar como aceita

Comment: O @Marconcílio postou uma, aceita a dele :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o campo é da mesma tabela e da mesma chave, você só precisa setar o campo com o valor da outra coluna.

```
update contas
set status='0',
    valor_recebido= valor_dasuacoluna
where id IN ($ids)
```

Agora se o campo for de outra chave (ID) diferente você terá que fazer um JOIN ou um sub select

```
   update contas
    set status='0',
        valor_recebido= (select valor_dasuacoluna from contas where  id = outroid)
    where id IN ($ids)
```

Comment: muito bom era isso mesmo ;)